# How to refresh a List View in admin on rest

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, admin-on-rest

I am trying to get a list to refresh after a custom action was successfully executed.

i used the saga from the admin on rest tutorial

```
function * actionApproveSuccess () {
  yield put(showNotification('Executed'))
  yield put(push('/comments')) 
  // does not refresh, because the route does not change
  // react-redux-router also has no refresh() method, like react-router has...
}
```

the other idea i had was to somehow trigger the refresh action of the list component, but i have no idea how to access that or how to hook that up to the ACTION_SUCCESS event.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to refresh a route via react router, and that's a [known problem](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/1982). Admin-on-rest's `List` component has [its own refresh mechanism](https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/blob/1ef944fe228bb13dda420d863170150209bb62af/src/mui/list/List.js#L120-L124), but offers no API for it.

My advice would be to use a custom `<List>` component based on admin-on-rest's one. And if you find a way to expose the `refresh` action, feel free to open a PR on the aor repository!

Answer (score 4):

@Danila Smirnov's answer above shows this message when I use it now:

> Deprecation warning: The preferred way to refresh the List view is to connect your custom button with redux and dispatch the refreshView action.

Clicking the refresh button itself wasn't working either nowadays.

Here's the tweaked version that I got working in mine.

Edit: Modified it a bit more to make it reusable.

---

**RefreshListActions.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import FlatButton from 'material-ui/FlatButton'
import { CardActions } from 'material-ui/Card'
import NavigationRefresh from 'material-ui/svg-icons/navigation/refresh'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { REFRESH_VIEW } from 'admin-on-rest/src/actions/uiActions'
import { refreshView as refreshViewAction } from 'admin-on-rest/src/actions/uiActions'

class MyRefresh extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        const { refreshInterval, refreshView } = this.props
        if (refreshInterval) {
            this.interval = setInterval(() => {
                refreshView()
            }, refreshInterval)
        }
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.interval)
    }

    render() {
        const { label, refreshView, icon } = this.props;
        return (
            <FlatButton
                primary
                label={label}
                onClick={refreshView}
                icon={icon}
            />
        );
    }
}

const RefreshButton = connect(null, { refreshView: refreshViewAction })(MyRefresh)

const RefreshListActions = ({ resource, filters, displayedFilters, filterValues, basePath, showFilter, refreshInterval }) => (
    <CardActions>
        {filters && React.cloneElement(filters, { resource, showFilter, displayedFilters, filterValues, context: 'button' }) }
        <RefreshButton primary label="Refresh" refreshInterval={refreshInterval} icon={<NavigationRefresh />} />
    </CardActions>
);

export default RefreshListActions
```

**In my list that I want to refresh so often:**

```
import RefreshListActions from './RefreshListActions'

export default (props) => (
    <List {...props}
        actions={<RefreshListActions refreshInterval="10000" />}
        >
        <Datagrid>
            ...
        </Datagrid>
    </List>
)
```

Comment: This is working. It is better if to created the button which has a drop down menu for auto update intervals, like disable, 10, 50, 100, etc. I see someone has similar idea in the other post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44551957/is-there-a-way-to-simulate-pressing-the-refresh-button-to-refresh-a-list. but no luck to make it work

Answer (score 3):

Definitely hacky, but a work-around could be:

```
push('/comments/1') //any path to change the current route
push('/comments') //the path to refresh, which is now a new route
```

Answer (score 2):

using refreshView action via redux works well.

see example....

```
import { refreshView as refreshViewAction } from 'admin-on-rest';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'; 

class MyReactComponent extends Component {
  //... etc etc standard react stuff...

 doSomething() {
    // etc etc do smt then trigger refreshView like below  
    this.props.refreshView();
 }
 render() {
   return <div>etc etc your stuff</div>
 }
}

export default connect(undefined, { refreshView: refreshViewAction })(
  MyReactComponent
);
```

Comment: This worked for me to refresh a list after a custom action has executed. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Awesome, but how do you do if you don't want to dispatch and just listen to refresh so I can fix UI not build with react-admin components?

Answer (score 1):

I've solve this task with small hack via Actions panel. I'm sure it is not correct solution, but in some situations it can help:

```js
class RefreshButton extends FlatButton {
  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.refreshInterval) {
      this.interval = setInterval(() => {
        this.props.refresh(new Event('refresh'))
      }, this.props.refreshInterval)
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval)
  }
}

const StreamActions = ({ resource, filters, displayedFilters, filterValues, basePath, showFilter, refresh }) => (
  <CardActions>
    {filters && React.cloneElement(filters, { resource, showFilter, displayedFilters, filterValues, context: 'button' }) }
    <RefreshButton primary label="Refresh streams" onClick={refresh} refreshInterval={15000} refresh={refresh} icon={<NavigationRefresh />} />
  </CardActions>
);

export default class StreamsListPage extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <List
        {...this.props}
        perPage={20}
        actions={<StreamActions />}
        filter={{ active: true }}
        title='Active Streams'>
        <StreamsList />
      </List>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Just tried it and it's showing an error and this notice: "Deprecation warning: The preferred way to refresh the List view is to connect your custom button with redux and dispatch the `refreshView` action."

Comment: It was an old version of package. There is no need this trick in modern app

Answer (score 1):

The `push` is just a redirect for AOR which did not seem to work for me either. What guleryuz posted was on the right track for me.. Here's what I did building on his example:

```
// Import Statement
import { refreshView as refreshViewAction } from 'admin-on-rest';

class RemoveButton extends Component {
handleClick = () => {
    const { refreshView, record, showNotification } = this.props;
    fetch(`http://localhost:33333/api/v1/batch/stage/${record.id}`, { method: 'DELETE' })
        .then(() => {
            showNotification('Removed domain from current stage');
            refreshView();
        })
        .catch((e) => {
            console.error(e);
            showNotification('Error: could not find domain');
        });
}

 render() {
    return <FlatButton secondary label="Delete" icon={<DeleteIcon />}onClick={this.handleClick} />;
 }
}
```

These bits are important as well:

```
RemoveButton.propTypes = {
record: PropTypes.object,
showNotification: PropTypes.func,
refreshView: PropTypes.func,
};

export default connect(null, {
showNotification: showNotificationAction,
refreshView: refreshViewAction,
})(RemoveButton);
```

So the way this works is it uses AOR's `refreshViewAction` as a prop function. This uses the underlying call to populate the data grid for me which is `GET_LIST`. This may not apply to your specific use case. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

[Pim Schaaf's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44685215/794071) solution worked like a charm for me, Mine looks a bit different

```
yield put(push('/comments/-1')); // This refreshes the data
yield put(showNotification('')); // Hide error
```